# No internet connection with browsers on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, networking, internet, browser

[Unable to browse Internet on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/281932/unable-to-browse-internet-on-mac-os-x)

My Problem is very similar to the one linked above; I can't reach websites using browsers, everything else like terminal stuff (ping...), Mail, Skype, OS X internal social networking etc. is still working.

The difference is, that

1. RockMelt, a Chrome-based browser, connects to the internet, whereas my usual browsers Safari, Chrome and Nightly don't.
2. `sudo killall mDNSResponder` does not solve the problem, not even temporarily.

After a reboot, all browser behave just the way they should for about 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

When my mac did something similar, I removed all network adapters in System Preferences/Networks (- symbol) and then apply, close, went back in and added them again with the + symbol. Reboot then all was ok.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried what you said, and after the reboot it all worked fine, but i just lost internet connection in Safari again.

Comment: Sounds quite serious - Can you create another login user instead? Sometimes creating a new user fixes the network issues.

Comment: For some reason, everything is working at the moment. I haven't changed anything intentionally, so I don't know why. We'll see for how long. Until then, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. All browsers but TOR were not working. Being an average Joe in terms of computing skills, i sifted aroung aimlessly and wihout luck until - Under **system preferences/network**, i deleted (using **+/-** sign) IPv4/v6 addresses that did not correspond to my MBP's. Do this for both connection type (wifi in my case) and the router. For each case, click on **advanced...** button then the **DNS** tab.